# Mock a void method with a delay

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How do I go about mocking a void method and also replace what that method executes? I'd like to mock the method so it does a thread.sleep to simulate work.

I've tried

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>(){
    Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return null;
    }
}.when(Class).myVoidMethod((OtherClass) Mockito.any());
```

but it complains that I'm not mocking it right and gives me examples of using doException or thenReturn.

Comment: I was passing in the wrong class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mockito Documentation

```
      stubVoid(mock)
  .toAnswer(new Answer() {
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMOck invocation) {
                    Visitor v = (Visitor) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                    v.visitMock(invocation.getMock());

                    return null;
                }
            })
   .on().accept(any());
```

The Answer will be executed

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/stubbing/VoidMethodStubbable.html